# Avoid loading modules already injected into the DOM with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

Is there a way to avoid loading modules that could already exist into the DOM?

Example:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    // jquery here is needed only if window.jQuery is undefined
    'jquery': '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min'
  }
});
```

It would be great to be able to use something like this snippet

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'jquery': {
       uri: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min',
       // if this function returns false or undefined load the script from the url
       define: function(){ return window.jQuery; } 
    }
  }
});
```

### -----------------------------------------------------------------

UPDATE

### -----------------------------------------------------------------

I sent a pull request to @jrburke on github https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/886 with my proposal. The fixed version of requirejs could be tested on here:

http://gianlucaguarini.com/experiments/requirejs/requirejs-test3.html

Here the requirejs configuration according to my API proposal

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    // jquery here is needed only if window.jQuery is undefined
    'jquery':'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min',
    'lodash':'//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.0.0/lodash.underscore.min',
    'backbone':'//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone-min'
  },
  shim:{
    'jquery':{
      // with my fix now I detect whether window.jQuery has been already defined
      // in this case I avoid to load the script from the cdn
      exports:'jQuery',
      // if this feature is missing I need to load the new jQuery from the cdn
      validate: function(){
        return  window.jQuery.Defferred;
      }
    },
    'lodash':{
      // lodash will be loaded only if it does not exist in the DOM
      exports:'_',
      // if this function returns false or undefined load the script from the cdn
      validate: function() {
        // is the lodash version already available in the DOM new enough for my application?
        return  window.parseInt(window._.VERSION) >= 2;
      }
    },
    'backbone':{
      deps:['lodash','jquery'],
      // if backbone exists we don't need to load it twice
      exports:'Backbone'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I have created an easy test to show you the problem with different versions of the same app core libraries http://gianlucaguarini.com/experiments/requirejs/requirejs-test1.html

Answer (score 2):

As @jrburke points out in your [pull-request](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/886), the way to do it is:

```
require.config({});

if (typeof jQuery === 'function') {
  define('jquery', function() { return jQuery; });
}

// start module loading here
require(['app'], function(app) {});
```

If a module is already defined, it won't be (re)loaded. Here, the definition is simply to re-use the already-loaded global `jQuery` object.

Answer (score 0):

As jQuery is AMD compatible, if it is already in the page Require.js won't load it again.

In a broader way, Require.js only looks the path configs when a module haven't been defined yet. So as soon you have a module defined, Require.js won't load it again:

```
define('jquery', [], function() { /* stuff */ });
//        ^ Module 'jquery' is defined here. Require.js won't load it twice.
```

Checkout this JsBin for a working example: http://jsbin.com/OfIBAxA/2/edit

Comment: I am not 100% sure this is going to work.. let me test it first

Comment: @GianlucaGuarini Your URL doesn't work. Here, check this JsBin: http://jsbin.com/OfIBAxA/2/edit

Comment: Maybe you loaded jQuery before Require.js library. In this case of course jQuery won't be able to register a module as Require's not available yet.

Comment: ops sorry http://gianlucaguarini.com/experiments/requirejs/requirejs-test1.html here we go

Comment: Ok let me be more explicit: I need to develop a module that could be used without requirejs; so my module will be build using almondjs that makes it available in any environment (even a non-amd env..). If my module depends on Backbone, lodash and jQuery I need to download these dependencies somewhere: if one of these dependencies is already used inside the page hosting my module than I will use it otherwise I need to download the dependencies not available from the cdn. Hoping now the concept is cleaner :)

Comment: The problem is your concept. There's a lot of failing point there. What if a user is using out dated dependencies (e.g. jQuery 1.2) on their site? Do you know almond cannot load external modules - it is not a loader, it only resolve dependencies for included modules? By module do you mean "plugin"? If that's the case, checkout UMD and don't include your dependencies, only add them in the README and the user will take care of it. If you have an app that user ember in their page, then use iFrames (à la Disqus et cie) and control your environment yourself - and don't break user website :)

Comment: I could show you just another example: http://gianlucaguarini.com/experiments/requirejs/requirejs-test2.html togetherjs is a cool module by Mozilla lab build using requirejs but build with almondjs. Check what happens when you init the script: it loads a huge package containing jQuery v1.8.3 even if jquery has already been loaded and available on the page...that's what I mean.. the dependencies version control could be handled with my solution above inside the requirejs config just returning the right flag to the function 'define'